# How can use Flyway with grails

Tags: grails, flyway

I know there is a Flyway2 plugin. However im not satisfied since it seems fitted for working by console commands. What i want is to integrate Flyway in a programatic way so:

1st Integration tests use flyway to handle db schema with H2 database

2nd Flyway get's triggered on tomcat deployment and handles also the environment database (maybe through running it from bootstrap?)

Does anyone has experienced with this?

EDIT after some discussion:

In order to use the plugin i would need to get a fully configured instance of GFlyway from spring context. This becomes difficult since the bean only property is `def config` from where it will read all the required properties. The question is how to replicate this behavior within the resources.groovy ... how to provide the application config as a parameter to the bean.

Comment: I don't have any experience in using this plugin but the source is available on github https://github.com/Vav1lon/GFlyway2 and of course there is nothing stopping you from implementing exactly what you want by examining how the command line scripts work and integrating those actions into your application. You may even consider forking the plugin and adding this feature/functionality to the plugin for others to make use of.

Comment: I've already looked at the plugin code ... but i found problems tweaking it to work in programatic way. I would need to raise a GFlyway bean in the spring context to be able to use it ... however i am not sure how to get a fully configured instance from the spring context (with same configuration tools used to work command line way) ... reached this point i am not sure if it's worth to keep with the plugin or integrate flyway directly. Thats the reason why i am asking for help here.

Comment: I mean ... i've tried to def GFlyway, or @Autowired GFlyway and finally GFlyway f = (GFlyway) grailsApplication.mainContext.getBean("gFlyway"); but seems bean is not available in context ... i've tried different names. Do you have any hint or suggestion from where to continue researching?. Thanks.

Comment: Looking at the plugin source if you need that class you will need to create it in `resources.groovy` as a bean. Something like: `gFlyaway(gflyway2.GFlyway)`. However, it also looks like there is work to be done about wiring up the configuration etc.

Comment: Exactly. It is easy to have a plain instance setting it up in the resources.groovy ... but i get into problems trying to get a fully configured instance ready to work with. Basically the constructor is feeded with the config ... from where it can read the different properties ... but i don't know how to replicate this in the resources.groovy :(

Answer (score 1):

As we have been discussing in the comments, the correct way to configure this as a bean would be:

```
// Resources.groovy
beans {
  grailsApplication = ref('grailsApplication')
  gFlyaway(gflyway2.GFlyway) {
    config = grailsApplication.config
  }
}
```

Configure the settings as usual within your `Config.groovy` per the [documentation](https://github.com/Vav1lon/GFlyway2) of the plugin.

That should get you closer, if not all the way there.

Comment: I get a weird "org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Unable to init metadata table "myAppName"."schema_version" with version 0 as this version was used for schema creation" ... but indeed it seems i have now the GFlyway instace configured! ... a big step ahead. Thanks.

Comment: Looking at AbstractFlyway.groovy it looks like the plugin only accepts a little subset of Flyway options. Options like baselineVersion or baselineOnMigrate that are very useful when working with already existent schemas are not supported AFAIK. This may be the reason of the error i get.

Comment: I was able to avoid this problem avoiding to call init. Instead i set grails.plugins.gflyway.initOnMigrate = true; and called migrate directly. This seems to work and now i complete the migration successfully (!). However i have a new problem since i get "XXX table not found" ... maybe is just schema selection problem